# How do I say "my car is broken" idiomatically?

Tags: american-english, british-english, synonyms

Hmm: the version I give has never sounded quite right to me, but as a non-native English speaker, I don't know how native American or English people say this.

So I'd be really glad if you could provide me with examples of more common ways of putting this in American and British English.

Somehow it doesn't sound right: I'd say something is broken if it's broken into pieces or something, but if it's not functioning properly it just doesn't feel right.

I've tried googling, and indeed in some forums this has been discussed, and some native speakers said that they don't say it that way (but that it actually is grammatically correct). Yet none has explained what they use instead! That's what I want to know. *How would you put it* as a native speaker?

The sources that I checked out before posting:

http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/98310-car-is-broken-vs-has-broken-down
http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/my-car-has-broken-broke-down.2721741/

Comment: Hello, Arturas M. Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth God, you guys are destroying the purpose of these sites and moving the users away by creating too many of them. A question of this kind could probably suit both sites. It clearly is on topic. I added the sources for you. But it really shouldn't be necessary...

Comment: If I hadn't a clue I'd say "My car is not working right", or "There's something wrong with my car".  But more likely I'd say "the engine is missing" or "the brakes seem to be dragging" or "there's a funny vibration coming from the right front wheel".

Comment: Though not very articulate, it is perfectly acceptable to say "my (car, TV, computer, marriage) is broken."  People will get the gist and know that you mean that there is something wrong of some nature or another.

Comment: Have you considered that ELU is for 'linguists and serious users ...'? Would you expect this level of question from such a person? There are _many_ other suitable websites. I'd submit that it is rather yourself who wants to homogenise diversity, to have ELU conform to _your_ wishes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Have you noticed the site is not called "English Language Usage for linguists and serious users"? If it was, everybody would consider it and not post here in a different context. So if you want it to be like that, call the site that way, not this way. In my case ELU is exactly what I'm looking for as I'm referring to all kinds of opinions on tihs, considering linguistically correct options and also looking at practical usage, etc...

Comment: 'English Language Learners Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for speakers of other languages learning English.' Why can't there be  a sister site reserved for linguists and those who have achieved a certain mastery of the language? I read about the target usership on ELU in the Help Center, and welcomed and accepted it – I didn't try to skew it in a different direction. When I was learning English, I didn't demand to be allowed into the sixth form. That was for people who'd progressed to a certain level. There was an ordered and well accepted structure to the school....

Comment: If I wanted to learn Lithuanian, I would not insist that some 'Lithuanian for linguists ...' site answered my basic questions – I'd look for a learners' group. But your English is good enough to use the ELL site. (I've edited your question to help you with a few points.)

Comment: Arturas M:  I don't have a rep of nearly 30,000 on this site, so maybe my opinion isn't worth much here.  I think you have asked a valid question for this site.  Maybe marginally valid, but certainly within the accepted bounds, as defined by many other questions which have not elicited grumpiness. (See, e.g., the Poopy-Head question and the one about bitching.)  I think your question is above the level of the ELL site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well if this site would be called "English for linguists" I surely would have never posted on this site, but it's "English language & usage" and this name perfectly suits what I was looking for, so just saying that you can't really blame me... Thanks for bringing Lithuanian up - but actually I'm pretty sure that the Lithuanian linguists would be happy that you're trying to learn Lithuanian and would be friendly and  glad to help you even if you posted in a site which would be called "Lithuanian for linguists"... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your car were sitting dead at the side of the road, an American would probably say "My car has broken down." If your car were then towed to a mechanic, who told you that the motor needs replacement, you might say "My car is broken.", although there are other possibilities.

Since you seem to be referring to your car being operable but not in good shape, neither choice would ordinarily be used. "My car needs work' or "There is something wrong with my car" seem more likely. All of these phrases, of course, are commonly padded with bad language that we don't need to consider here.

In both cases, "broken" or "broken down" usually mean inoperative, although the scale of such a condition is determined by other aspects of the sentence. To say "My tail-lights are broken" does not mean you cannot physically drive the car, but legally you should not, and you will get a ticket if a police officer spots you. For that matter, in some cases a sufficient level of brokenness in a vehicle will get the vehicle declared unsafe to drive, and the police may have it towed, even though it can still move under its own power.

Comment: actually in the case where the engine is damaged, you would say that the *engine* is broken, or shot, rather than the car. Cars are viewed as a system. About the only thing you can do to the car as a whole is **wreck** it.

Comment: With all due respect, I think we'll have to agree to disagree. If asked, "Can you give me a lift to the store?", a response of "Sorry, but my car's broken."  would be easier and more natural than "Sorry, but my car's engine is dead." It is exactly because a car is viewed as a system that referring to the system as being broken is appropriate when the ability of the system to function is the subject - particularly when speaking casually.

Comment: It would be more natural to say your car has broken down, which is what you would say 99 percent of the time or more.  I've never heard a car described as broke outside of jokes.

Comment: A more natural reply to the request for a lift would be "My car's out of action right now", or "My car's in the shop", possibly followed by some elaboration as to its particular malady.

Comment: Everyone will understand you if you say "my car is broken".  They will also peg you as a foreigner, which is OK.  Saying "my car's broken down" or "my car isn't working", or "my car is out of commission", or "my car won't start" sounds more natural.

Comment: Eh - I'm an engineer. I talk about things being broken, cars among them, and no one thinks I'm ESL.

Comment: If your intuition is correct that they are talking about "your car being operable but not in good shape" then [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decrepit_car) would be a good source for more options. When I read that quote I immediately thought of "jalopy" or "clunker."